# iOS communication between applications

Tags: ios

I'm currently planning out an application for a friend who has a series of applications he wants to build all connected. Because this will be our first project, he wants to build only one as a pilot to see how I do. My issue is, is it possible for two built applications to share the same information database?
(For experience, I've only had 1 quarter of android app dev fall '11)

Comment: You are asking if two applications can share the same database? Is this database on a remote server? Then yes. Is this database local to the phone? Much more difficult/impossible.

Comment: @Leeish is it even worth considering the second condition?

Comment: I would say no. While I wouldn't say it's impossible, but the only way I could even see if happening, you would still need to route the data through a central server, in which case you might as well have the DB on your server. Imagine trying to send/receive data from many devices at once, through a server, to try to keep their local DB's in sync. It would be a nightmare to the point it would be impossible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By design, for security, iOS apps are sandboxed and cannot share local data. There is thus no way to share a local database between two apps and still get your app approved for App Store distribution, unless Apple relaxes things with the release of iOS 7 at WWDC next week (and there's no indication this is going to happen).

As @Leeish says, the only way to share data between apps is with your own custom server-based solution.

I personally use [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) with the [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) iOS library for sharing data over the web, along with the [Objectify API](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) to make web-based database work simple. This combination is very robust and doesn't cost a penny unless you're getting really serious levels of traffic.

Comment: I was going to say the same, so just an upvote will do. My solution differs on the weapon of choice on the server side only.

Comment: @danutenshu No problems! btw - Don't let the title of the ASIHttpRequest website to put you off, while is not being developed is very good and very quick to get going.